# Sorting not working with Knockout and Isotope and non-trivial template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-isotope, knockout-3.0

Trying to make a list of users sortable by different criteria with animation. Was already using Knockout so [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/ACSGx/) seemed like a good direction to take. I switched to an Isotope 2.0 fork of the integration code [here](https://gist.github.com/David-Desmaisons/a097dbf59604367f2842). I've run into two issues that I'm not sure how to resolve. First is at [Sorting not working with Knockout and Isotope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303258).

The sorting doesn't work at all with a non-trivial template, as shown in this version - http://codepen.io/matelich/pen/zvYOam/

Working:

```
<div data-bind="text: UserName"></div>
```

Not:

```
<div class="user_row" >
  <div data-bind="text: UserName"></div>
  <img src="http://marketingmobil.mobi/login/uploads/783/48455.png" />
</div>
```

The `user_row` class is being set for Isotope's `itemSelector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var ViewModel = {
    users: ko.observableArray(),
    getOptions: function() {
      return {
        layoutMode: 'vertical',
        itemSelector: '.user_row'
      };
    },
  };
```

i.e. itemSelector with '.user_row'(with dot)